# I can't install Spotify

Tags: software-installation, spotify

I tried to install Spotify like million times and every time I got stuck after second step. This is what terminal writes:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.yVHjNKwkbK --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
gpg: požaduji klíč 94558F59 ze hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

The last sentence means, that 'I need key 94558F59 from hkp server keyserver...' and I don't know what to do

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. When asking questions, please include the actual commands you ran. We have no idea what the "second step" is (or the first, for that matter) and we don't know what command you ran gives you this error. Without this information, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 2):

*** Big Warning ***

Adding keys manually that haven't been verified can be a security risk!

That said, the content of the key can be found at http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x082CCEDF94558F59. Let's manually add it.

```
sudo apt-key add -
```

This will put you on a new line. Copy and paste the content of the key into your terminal, press enter, and then press CTRL+D.

If you're somehow blocked from the server, the key content is as follows:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.1.4
Comment: Hostname: keyserver.ubuntu.com
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=HvND
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Then do the update and install.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install spotify-client -y
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to leave now but I wiil try it later

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how but I finally did it! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This really should only require three commands.

Add the Spotify repository.

```
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Add the GPG key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Update and install Spotify.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client -y
```

Comment: Again, it writes the same message :-/ I have Pear OS 7. Is it possible I can't install Spotify? I have Linux onlu for few months and before I was usual Mycrosoft user, so I don't know much stuff about terminal and so on

Comment: Hrm. They key is very much there, and served up by the keyserver. I wonder if it's possible that you're somehow blocked from accessing the server. 

Can you trying pinging it? 

ping keyserver.ubuntu.com

You should see a response similar to:

PING keyserver.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from boquila.canonical.com (91.189.89.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=87.7 ms